# Error de paquetes de Nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

he desarrollado una api web net Core 2.1 en vs2019 y todo anda bien , así que decidí pasar el desarrollo servidor de DES que no tiene conexión a internet, pase el proyecto mas sus dependencias de nuget todo de manera local pero , al copilar la solución tengo estos warning ,inicie el proyecto y lo que sale es el siguiente mensaje "No se puede mostrar esta página" cosa que en mi local si carga sin ningún problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es que tengas conexión a internet para obtener los NuGets pero si copiaste  el proyecto incluyendo sus dependencias puedes restaurar los NuGets, dando clic derecho a la solución y selecciona la opción "Restore NuGet Packages":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Comment: Si , realice lo mismo y me salía el mismo error , así que cree un proyecto desde cero  por default el controlador valué , al ejecutarlo sale igual así que creo que es un problema del servidor

Comment: De hecho en la imagen que agregaste se indica que se restauraron los NuGet, así que probablemente es problema de la app o como dices del servidor Samuel.